# How to see webcam in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, webcam

I don't have any idea what IM client would I use in Ubuntu 9.10. And how do I access the webcam in the Acer Aspire laptop. Do I need any drivers for this one?
I've tried to install XP on virtual box in Ubuntu. But the webcam isn't accessible when I use yahoo. What do I do?

Comment: What model of Aspire have you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general advise I'd suggest you to take a look at [Ubuntu's documentation about webcams](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam).

Answer (score 0):

You may well have [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) already installed. Otherwise:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```